# browserify and browserify-shim, do we really need browserify-shim?

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify, browserify-shim

I am trying to figure out what the difference between browserify and browserify-shim. After reading a few tutorial, the only difference I found that is to make required function or libraries to global scope?

browserify makes all js files to one single file without dependency conflict or issues.

```
var $ = require('jquery'); 
$('body').css('background','red');
```

> browserify main.js -o bundle.js

so we can just include bundle.js in html file, but we are unable to use $ in html, as jQuery is not in global environment.

browserify-shim is for making jQuery to global scope?

```
"browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$"
  }
```

But if only for making jQuery to global scope, I think we can simply done by using this
`var $ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");` in browserify

So my question is that, do we really need browserify-shim or if there is something else we need from browserify-shim but we are unable to do it though browserify?